# Watson NLU Order Of entities returned

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, watson-nlu, watson-knowledge-studio

I am using watson NLU along with a custom model to extract education entities from a resume.

So far, it works okay, but if there is more than one education mentioned, it doesn't return the result in order.

for example, if a resume contains high school and university, it returns the data in the wrong order as shown below:

```
 {
    "type": "GraduationYear",
    "text": "2007",
    "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
        "Date"
        ]
    },
    "count": 1
},
{
    "type": "Institution",
    "text": "Rahman Colledge",
    "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
        "CollegeUniversity"
        ]
    },
    "count": 1
},
{
    "type": "GraduationYear",
    "text": "2017",
    "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
        "Date"
        ]
    },
    "count": 1
},

{
    "type": "Institution",
    "text": "MIS Highschool",
    "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
        "School"
        ]
    },
    "count": 1
},
{
    "type": "EducationLevel",
    "text": "Diploma",
    "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
        "Degree"
        ]
    },
    "count": 1
},
{
    "type": "EducationLevel",
    "text": "High School Certfication",
    "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
        "Degree"
        ]
    },
    "count": 1
}
```

How can I order the results found from the model itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new *mentions* parameter in the NLU API that returns the locations of the entities in the text when set to *true*. You can then use the start index of each entity to order them. [See the NLU API reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#entities).